# Changing images for a slidehow, is CKFinder the best solution?

Tags: php, slideshow, ckfinder, w3-css

We use CKEditor in combination with CKFinder for changing items on our site. But now we got a slideshow with images that are on our server. Editing the slideshow with the full CKEditor can be hard. We have to add classes on ourself and viewing pictures in CKEditor inst that clear.

I guess i would only use CKFinder for editing the slideshow and pass the classes automatic. But i cant find anything online and ive tried altering the configuration but that only makes things worse. Can you help me in the right direction or is CKFinder not the best software for this purpose?

Comment: A slideshow is HTML, CSS, JavaScript and images while CKFinder is just images. You use it to keep, organize and edit your image files on server. In order to add CSS class to an image, the URL to the image has to be put in `img` tag and class needs to be add to that tag. Now that's HTML with CSS which you manage in CKEditor and not CKFinder. If you have problems with editing your slideshow, you can always create a dedicated plugin for that in the editor: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html.

Comment: okay haven't thought that far but now you say it that isnt possible. But is there any other software which i can use?